# Reg.sub regex help in Python to normalize directory/file to play nice with Windows

Tags: python, regex, unicode, substitution

Very new here, and I am trying to modify some python code to normalize directory/file names for Windows using regular expression. I have searched and found lots of code examples, but haven’t quite figured out how to put it all together.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I need to remove all invalid Windows characters so directory/file names do not include: < > : " / \ | ? * 
Windows also doesn’t seem to like spaces at the end of a directory/file name. Windows also doesn’t like periods at the end of directory names.

So, I need to get rid of ellipsis without affecting the extension. To clarify, when I say ellipsis, I am referring to a pattern of three periods, and NOT the single unicode character “Horizontal Ellipsis (U+2026)”. I have researched and found multiple ways of doing individual parts of this, but I cannot see to get it all together and playing nice.

```
return unicode(re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', "", filename)
```

This cleans up the names, but not the pattern of two or more periods.

```
return unicode(re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*.]', "", filename)
```

This cleans up the names, but also affects the file extension.

```
[^\w\-_\. ]
```

This also seemed to be a viable alternative. It is a bit more restrictive than necessary, but I did find it easy to just keep adding specific characters I wanted to ignore.

```
\.{2,}
```

This is the piece I can’t seem to get to integrate with any of these methods. I understand that this should match two or more “.”, but leave a single “.” alone. But there are some situations where I “might” be left with a period at the end of a Windows directory name, which won’t work.

```
.*[.](?!mp3$)[^.]*$
```

I searched and found this specific snippet, which looks promising to match/ignore a specific extension. In my case, I want .mp3 left alone. Maybe a different way to go about things. And I think it might eliminate a potential problem of having a period at the end of a directory name.

Thank you for your time!

Edit: Additional Information Added

---

```
def normalize_filename(self, filename):
    """Remove invalid characters from filename"""
    return unicode(re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', "", filename))

def get_outfile(self):
    """Returns output filename based on song information"""
    destination_dir = os.path.join(self.normalize_filename(self.info["AlbumArtist"]),
                                   self.normalize_filename(self.info["Album"]))
    filename = u"{TrackNumber:02d} - {Title}.mp3".format(**self.info)
    return os.path.join(destination_dir, self.normalize_filename(filename))
```

This is the relevant code I am trying to modify. The full code basically pulls song artist, album, and track descriptions out of a sqlite database file. Then based on that information, it creates an artist directory, album directory, and a mp3 file.

However, because of Windows naming restrictions, those names need to be normalized/sanitized.

Ideally I would like this to be done with a single re.sub, if it can be done.
return unicode(re.sub(r'[<>:"/\|?*]', "", filename))

If there is another/better way to make this code work, I am open to it. But with my limited understanding, adding more complexity was beyond me, so I was trying to work within the bounds of what I currently understand. I have done a lot of reading over the past few days, but can’t quite accomplish what I would like to do.

For Example: “Ned’s Atomic Dustbin\ARE YOU NORMAL?\Not Sleeping Around” needs to become C:\Ned’s Atomic Dustbin\ARE YOU NORMAL\Not Sleeping Around.mp3

Another: “Green Day\UNO... DOS... TRÉ!\F*** Time” needs to become C:\Green Day\UNO DOS TRÉ\F Time.mp3”

Another: “Incubus\A Crow Left Of The Murder…\Pistola” would become C:\Incubus\A Crow Left Of The Murder\Pistola.mp3

Tricky Example: “System Of A Down\B.Y.O.B.\B.Y.O.B.” to C:\System Of A Down\BYOB\BYOB.mp3” Windows wouldn’t care if it was B.Y.O.B, but the last period is what causes issues. So it would probably be best if the solution eliminated all “.”, except on the extension .mp3.

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are asking. Do you want 1 regex to do all these things or can it be multiple?

Comment: Please also add some example input and your desired resulting output given such input. Try to cover corner cases, should be easy as it seems you have already given them considerable thought

Comment: `def normalize_filename(self, filename):
        return unicode(re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', "", filename))

    def get_outfile(self):
        destination_dir = os.path.join(self.normalize_filename(self.info["AlbumArtist"]),
                                       self.normalize_filename(self.info["Album"]))
        filename = u"{TrackNumber:02d} - {Title}.mp3".format(**self.info)
        return os.path.join(destination_dir, self.normalize_filename(filename))`

This is the relevant code I am trying to modify.

Comment: @WillBarnwell Ideally I would like this to be done with a single re.sub, if it can be done.
return unicode(re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', "", filename))

Comment: @WillBarnwell Tricky Example: “System Of A Down\B.Y.O.B.\B.Y.O.B.” to C:\System Of A Down\BYOB\BYOB.mp3” Windows wouldn’t care if it was B.Y.O.B, but the last period is what causes issues. So it would probably be best if the solution eliminated all “.”, except on the extension .mp3.

Comment: @WillBarnwell Another: “Green Day\UNO... DOS... TRÉ!\F*** Time” needs to become C:\Green Day\UNO DOS TRÉ\F Time.mp3”

Another: “Incubus\A Crow Left Of The Murder…\Pistola” would become C:\Incubus\A Crow Left Of The Murder\Pistola.mp3

Comment: Thanks for adding the info, hope you get a good answer :)

Comment: If you get an answer that solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is totally based on the text below (you typed, of course):

> I need to remove all invalid Windows characters so directory/file names do not include: < > : " / \ | ? * Windows also doesn’t seem to like spaces at the end of a directory/file name. Windows also doesn’t like periods at the end of directory names.

So here we go (for **file/directory**):
`unicode(re.sub(r'(\<|\>|\:|\"|\/|\\|\||\?|\*', '', file/directory))`

Explanation:
  `\<|\>|\:|\"|\/|\\|\||\?|\*` <= matches alll of your undesired chars

At this time you will have erased all of your undesired chars *EXCEPT* the spaces/dots at the end of the name.

For yours `file_name` you can update its variable with
`file_name = re.sub(r'( +)$', '', file_name)`
  `( +)$` <= matches spaces or a dot at the **end** of the string.
and you'll be done because there are no more restrictions besides that the name can't contain any spaces at its end (remember we already removed the special chars).

For *directories* however, you can't have both *periods* **and** *spaces.*
So the best way, my opinion of course, is to implement a **recursive** procedure, once that stops *only* when:

> `dir_name == re.sub(r'( +|\.+)$', '', dir_name)`

and `dir_name` keeps being updated with `dir_name = re.sub(r'( +|\.+)$', '', dir_name)` while the above statement is *false*.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LordDagon32thanks for asking and being a nice guy that upvote some answer that was useful for you :)